# Postgres 15.3 fails to create new tablespace (could not set permissions)

Tags: postgresql, permissions, tablespaces

I am unable to create new tablespaces on a fresh Postgres 15.3 installation on Ubuntu 22.04. I tried the following so far:

- re-install Postgres
- fully loosen file system permission
- disabled SELinux

But still the postgres user reports it cannot set permissions on the tablespace folder. The log is below.

```
$ mkdir -p /media/user/Work/Databases/geo

$ chown -R postgres:postgres /media/user/Work/Databases

$ sudo chmod -R 777 /media/user/Work/Databases

$ setenforce 0
setenforce: SELinux is disabled

$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled

$ sudo su postgres
postgres@luis-workstation:/home/user$ psql
could not change directory to "/home/user": Permission denied
psql (15.3 (Ubuntu 15.3-1.pgdg22.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE TABLESPACE geo
  OWNER postgres
  LOCATION '/media/user/Work/Databases/geo';
ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "/media/user/Work/Databases/geo": Permission denied
```

Comment: does `cd /media/user/Work/Databases` works with postgres shell user?

Comment: @Sahap yes, all users have permission to `cd` into the /media folder and its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL insists on changing the permissions of the directory. This is the equivalent of running the following as operating system user `postgres`:

```bash
chmod 0700 /media/user/Work/Databases/geo
```

So you should get the same error message about missing permissions.

The user `postgres` must own `geo`:

```bash
chown postgres:postgres /media/user/Work/Databases/geo
```

Moreover, the user must have read (`r`) and execute (`x`) permissions on **all** directories in the hierarchy. For example:

```bash
chmod o+rx /media/user/Work/Databases
```